# Failed to convert a Numpy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type Nonetype)?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, chatbot

Exception has occurred: ValueError
Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type NoneType).
File "C:\Users\rdterrte\fghfghfg\dfgdgfd\fhggdffd\chatbot.py", line 35, in predict_class
res = model.predict(np.asarray([bow]))[0]
File "C:\Users\rdterrte\fghfghfg\dfgdgfd\fhggdffd\chatbot.py", line 58, in 
ints = predict_class(message)
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type NoneType).

```
import random
import json
import pickle
import numpy as np

import nltk
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer

from tensorflow import keras 
from keras.models import load_model

lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
intents = json.loads(open('intents.json').read())

words = pickle.load(open('words.pkl', 'rb'))
classes = pickle.load(open('classes.pkl', 'rb'))
model = load_model('chatbot_model.model')

def clean_up_sentence(sentence):
sentence_words = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
sentence_words = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in sentence_words]
return sentence_words

def bag_of_words(sentence):
sentence_words = clean_up_sentence(sentence)
bag = [0] * len(words)
for w in sentence_words:
    for i, word in enumerate(words):
        if word == w:
            bag[i] = 1
            return np.array(bag)
        
def predict_class(sentence):
        bow = bag_of_words(sentence)
        res = model.predict(np.array([bow]))[0]
        ERROR_THRESHOLD = 0.25
        result = [[i, r] for i, r in enumerate(res) if r > ERROR_THRESHOLD]

        results.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
        return_list = []
        for r in results:
             return_list.append({'intent': classes[r[0]], 'probability': str(r[1])})
             return return_list
```

Comment: I would recommend fixing your indentation here, it's clearly wrong and could lead to confusion.

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow tensors cannot have NaN values; you will have to deal with them in some way, such as by removing rows that contain them or filling it in with an average.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.

Which part of the code do you mean? And what do you mean by removing rows that contain them or filling it in with an average?

Comment: I think the line `res = model.predict(np.array([bow]))[0]` is causing the error. Can you try printing `bow` out on the line before it? It probably has a None somewhere, and TensorFlow doesn't allow that.